# Pandas - why does this fail to correct convert the column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm first taking a slice of a DF, then I'm converting a column in that dataframe to datetime format. However, for some reason it doesn't work? It's almost definitely linked to chaining and the usual confusions around SettingWithCopyWarning.

What I do...

I have a dataframe, df, consisting of a number of columns.. one of them is "Date".

1) Take a slice (for whatever reason)

```
df_filt = df.loc[df.items.isin(list_of_items)]
```

2a. Convert Date column to datetime (This works and correctly converts the filtered dataframe column, "Date" to time date)

```
df_filt['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filt.Date)
```

2b. Convert Date column to datetime (This does nothing)

```
df_filt.loc['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filt.Date)
```

Is 2a the correct way to do this? And why does 2b not do anything?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A small sample of your dataframe would be helpful.

Comment: So 2b will never work because `pd.DataFrame.loc` lets you slice *by index* if you only have one indexing argument. You can try `df_filt.loc[:, 'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filt.loc[:, 'Date'])`. I recommend you read [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).